# MAAS credentials for open stack

Tags: maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I was installing Open-stack on my Ubuntu machine. I have successfully installed MAAS and am able to access the GUI. Everything went well but I am stuck at the point where i have to start installing Autopilot for Openstack. Here I have two issues

1. `sudo openstack-install`  does not work but these commands found on Ask Ubuntu got me through:

   ```
   sudo apt install conjure-up
   conjure-up openstack
   ```
2. I could not login into MAAS when I chose to install Autopilot for Openstack. I need help here. I have used the credentials i use to login to MAAS GUI but it gives me this error:

[image: Gives me this error..what does 3 items separated by colon mean]

I gave my mass server as **http://127.0.0.1/MAAS**
and oauth as the MAAS login password.

How to deal with this? is the server name I provided correct? What does "3 items separated by colons" mean? Should I change any text files for login?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give conjure-up the MAAS API credentials, not your login credentials.

Go to the MAAS GUI (as admin or a regular user), click on your name on the top right, select "account". There you will see "MAAS Keys". If it's empty, just generate one.

That's the text you need to give conjure-up, and is what it means by "3 items separated by colons": it's because the MAAS API key is like text:text:text.